# OOP: Call method of creating object from class handler

Tags: python, oop

I'm working on creating a simple start/stop HTTP Server python app, and I currently have the following class setup:

```
#The Tkinter interface for the application
class Application():
    def __init__(self,win):
        self.serverThread=ServerThread()

        self.output=Tkinter.Text(win)
        self.output.pack()


#The Server Thread
class ServerThread():
    class ServerHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def log_message(msg):
            //here's where I'm confused
    def __init__(self):
        self.server=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('',8000),self.ServerHandler)
```

What would be the correct way to add text the the output field in my application from the ServerHandler class without using a global output variable? Does ServerHandler even have a reference to the ServerThread object that created it?

**Edit: I guess what I'm really looking for is this: How can I let ServerHandler, which is passed as a class to BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer - know about the ServerThread and Application objects created without using global variables?**

Comment: It's not clear how the `ServerThread` class works. `self` would not be defined in the class declaration. Did you mean to put it in an `__init__` method?

Comment: That I did, I have it that way in my code, just removed a bit too much for the question. I have the code working with a global output reference to the text field, but I'd rather not have to do that if there's some way I can pass a reference to either the ServerThread object or Application object to the handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for logging facilities, I would recommend that you check out the standard [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module. In effect, it gives you as many "global" logging outputs as you want. It also obviously has the advantage of being standard: this makes logging code more legible, as many people use this method.